# Column sorting based on other column group in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

Among the repeating OG groups in the data frame named N0 on R, I want to list the ones whose ID values start with ENSG one by one and then list the values starting with ENSMG with the same OG value. In the codes I have tried so far, either OG is reordered or ID values become NA. Can you help me with this?

This is the frist part of my data frame:

```
 HOG   OG    `Gene Tree Parent Clade` ID                   species
  <chr> <chr> <chr>                    <chr>                <chr>  
 1 15    14    4                        ENSMUSG00000096424.1  Mmu    
 2 15    14    4                        ENSMUSG00000096409.3  Mmu    
 3 15    14    4                        ENSMUSG00000052058.3  Mmu    
 4 15    14    4                        ENSMUSG00000044205.7  Mmu    
 5 15    14    4                        ENSMUSG00000095527.3  Mmu    
 6 15    14    4                        ENSMUSG00000096167.4  Mmu    
 7 15    14    4                        ENSMUSG00000066748.4  Mmu
 8 14    14    1                        ENSG00000170953.3     Hsa    
 9 22    21    1                        ENSG00000198105.15    Hsa    
10 22    21    1                        ENSMUSG00000030145.14 Mmu    
11 23    21    2                        ENSG00000196597.13    Hsa    
12 23    21    2                        ENSG00000189180.16    Hsa
```

One of the code I have tried

```
custom_sort <- function(df) {
  unique_ogs <- unique(df$OG)
  
  result <- data.frame()
  
  for (og in unique_ogs) {
    subset_df <- df[df$OG == og, ]
    
    ensg_sorted <- subset_df[order(as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", subset_df$ID))), ]
    
  
    ensmusg_sorted <- subset_df[order(as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", subset_df$ID))), ]
    
    result <- rbind(result, ensg_sorted, ensmusg_sorted)
  }
  
  return(result)
}

result_df <- custom_sort(N0)
```

It duplicates all the values

Comment: Sounds like you want to sort first by `OG`, then by `ID` reversed. With `library(dplyr)` you can do `arrange(N0, OG, desc(ID))`. Or in base R `N0[order(-N0$OG, N0$ID, decreasing = TRUE)]`.

Comment: Suggested duplicate FAQ, [Sort (order) data frame rows by multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1296646/903061)

Comment: Oops, missed a comma in my base R suggestion. It should be `N0[order(-N0$OG, N0$ID, decreasing = TRUE), ]`

Comment: The other option you could try is creating another column that is `0`/`FALSE` for `"ENSG..."` and `1`/`TRUE` for `"ENSMUSG..."`, and then you could sort by `OG` and that column. Something like `N0$MUSG_fl = grepl("^ENSMUSG", N0$ID)` followed by `N0[order(N0$OG, N0$MUSG_fl), ]`. All of these should work fine.